# Why does this desktop look like this?

Tags: windows, desktop-customization, rainmeter

I was browsing [this list here](http://www.chip.de/bildergalerie/Die-schoensten-User-Desktops-2010-Galerie_46102963.html), and came across the following customised example of a user's desktop...

[image: custom user desktop]

... and I'd like to know how it was done. What program(s)/tools did the user use to customise it?

Comment: Sorry, but we're unlikely going to give you better information. Your only other option is to contact the author of your image as he is the only person who has the exact information, as it's are just some filled circles with the middle clock of Rainmeter Enigma moved, the information moved around and all other things hidden. Not that hard to reproduce if you really want this...

Comment: @Hashim:  Did you *re-upload* that image from imgur to imgur?  Please don’t do that.

Comment: @G-Man actually - there's an ongoing project to move http image links to https links as needed. Just changing the link would have done, but its not completely out of line.

Comment: I've gotten into a habit of doing so for the sake of the http>https project due to not being able to make edits less than 6 characters, but where I'm making other edits anyway, I should probably get into a habit of just adding the "s" into the `imgur` link.

Comment: I don't agree with this being too broad, though. It's fairly easy to identify for anyone who knows of Rainmeter and launcher docks, which is what ended up happening with the chosen answer. Can see it being a very useful question that could lead a lot of people to programs like Rainmeter.

Comment: @JourneymanGeek: I'm well aware of the https project, and that's exactly my point: Changing the link was all that was necessary. I want to make sure that people who're fixing the image links don't think that ***re-uploading*** images from imgur to imgur is the ideal way to do it.

Comment: @Hashim:  If you add the `s`, and also ``[``…``][1]``, that’s six.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Please note that this is not a desktop shell replacement, as you are just using the Windows task bar.

The background is a simple gradient with a stock image centered.

As for the clock and other info in the upper right corner, that's a custom version of [Rainmeter Enigma](http://ciaron23.deviantart.com/art/Rainmeter-Enigma-147599115):

[image]

You can [get Rainmeter](http://rainmeter.net/RainCMS/), which comes with the above theme.

> Rainmeter is a desktop customization platform. Through Rainmeter, you can enhance your Windows computer at home or work with skins: handy, compact applets which float freely on your desktop, much like Windows Sidebar gagdgets, or dashboard widgets for the Mac. **Rainmeter skins provide you with useful information at a glance.** It's easy to keep an eye on your system resources, like memory and battery power, or your online data streams, including email, RSS feeds, and weather forecasts. Many skins are even functional: they can record your notes and to-do lists, launch your favorite applications, and send your tweets to Twitter - all in a clean, unobtrusive interface that you can rearrange and customize to your liking.

---

The icons you see beneath the image are an [ObjectDock](http://www.stardock.com/products/objectdock/).

> ObjectDock is a dock similar to that in the Aqua GUI. It is distributed by Stardock for Windows 2000, 2003, XP, Vista and 7, and comes in Free and Plus versions. It allows the user to place shortcuts to any program in a "dock." This provides Windows users **functionality similar to that of Mac OS X**. The program comes in two versions, free, and a paid version offering more features. Both are available at their official website.
>   ObjectDock can be used as a program launcher, or as a complete taskbar replacement. Its functionality can be enhanced with plugins to provide features such as weather forecasts or news.

[image]

The above icon set is called [Ecqlipse 2](http://www.google.com/images?q=Ecqlipse+2), it contains the Firefox icon (third icon in the black section) but it seems like not all icons are taken from the same set. Anyhow, you might be able to find other icons by looking for monochrome or black and white icon sets...

Comment: And why did I receive two downvotes? Care to explain? Read the comment to the OP (which has not done the downvotes, he didn't vote on this site yet) and explain me how I can improve my answer?

Comment: Yeah, I don't get it either. I'm very thankful for your answer. Thing is, these custom icons might come in some package together with the rest. I think I've seen similar ones sometime ... I can't contact the author because he isn't mentioned on the original site

Comment: +1 for a clear answer and to get you back to neutral.

Comment: @FelixDombek: Added something about the dock and one of the icons, but it really looks like different things have been took together. Found that through [SashasDesk @ Flickr](http://www.flickr.com/photos/29349409@N07/2899657121/)...